# How to track example.com and example.de in same property with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, multiple-domains

I have two domains, `example.com` & `example.de` and I want to track both of them with [google analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/) but I want both of them in the same poperty but different data views.

Does somebody have any idea about how to do this?

Kind regards, Freddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have visits across both domains? If so, you should implement cross-domain tracking and then create separate views for each version.

On the other hand it's possible to have the same UA ID number on different domains and collect the data together. If you're using Universal Analytics, make sure the domain is set to 'auto'.

Comment: thanks. this worked for me!

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X' , window.location.hostname);

with the same UA ID on both domains